# Mondrian cube restriction

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, pentaho-cde, saiku, pentaho-ctools

once again i'am thankful to the kind attention given as much as i am to user4637357. To be more explicit on the reason of my question i have this cube schema .

```
<Schema name="Pentaho CE Audit">
```

my aim here is to rend this schema only accessible by the admin User, so i added

```
<Role name="admin">
    <SchemaGrant access="all">
    </SchemaGrant>  
</Role>
```

Before the Schema closing tag. Then i reloaded the file on the system. however after those configuration the cube is not longer accessible neither by the admin or any other users. my question here is to get from you guys the right way forward to set correct criteria on the system in view of restricting access to this cube please.

Comment: Are you using plain notepad++ to build the schema or you are using a validator such as http://ivy-is.co.uk/ivyse-ivy-schema-editor/?

Comment: I am using Plain notepad ++

Comment: Be careful for syntax errors. I strongly suggest to download the suggested validator. It saved my life after I found out about it.

Comment: Nice discovers to explore. Thank you.